# How do I retrieve a Django model class dynamically?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Without having the full module path of a Django model, is it possible to do something like:

```
model = 'User' [in Django namespace]
model.objects.all()
```

...as opposed to:

```
User.objects.all().
```

EDIT: I am trying to make this call based on command-line input. Is it possible to avoid the import statement, e.g.,

```
model = django.authx.models.User
```

Without Django returning the error:

```
"global name django is not defined."
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model
model = get_model('app_name', 'model_name')
```

There are other methods, of course, but this is the way I'd handle it if you don't know what models file you need to import into your namespace.  (Note there's really no way to safely get a model without first knowing what app it belongs to.  Look at the source code to loading.py if you want to test your luck at iterating over all the apps' models.)

**Update for Django 1.7+:** According to Django's [deprecation timeline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-9), `django.db.models.loading` has been deprecated in Django 1.7 and will be removed in Django 1.9. As pointed out in [Alasdair's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28380435/996114), 
In Django 1.7+, there is an [applications registry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#module-django.apps). You can use the [`apps.get_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model) method to dynamically get a model:

```
from django.apps import apps
MyModel = apps.get_model('app_label', 'MyModel')
```

Comment: In retrospect, I think he's looking for this as well.

Comment: All these are useful answers (my problem could be solved a variety of ways), but this one most directly addresses what I am looking for.

Answer (score 52):

For Django 1.7+, there is an [applications registry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#module-django.apps). You can use the [`apps.get_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model) method to dynamically get a model.

```
from django.apps import apps
MyModel = apps.get_model('app_label', 'MyModel')
```

Comment: Now that `django.db.models.loading` has been [deprecated in Django 1.9](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b53b4d5c107dbd56386c599582f46c522877a651/docs/internals/deprecation.txt), this is probably the best approach for dynamically loading a model in Django.

Comment: Oops, `django.db.models.loading` was actually deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9. Thanks @Alasdair for clarifying that in the edit to the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/411880/996114).

Comment: Lifesaver solution for circular references collisions.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as `django.db.models.loading` is deprecated in Django 1.9: https://github.com/django/django/blob/b53b4d5c107dbd56386c599582f46c522877a651/docs/internals/deprecation.txt

Comment: Is there a similar way to select ModelForms also ?

Comment: @WaqarAli You can have multiple model forms for the same model or models without a model form, so there isn’t a similar method for model forms. You might find `model form_factory` useful - it allows you to create a model form for a model.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.authx.models import User
model = User
model.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Classes are "first class" objects in Python, meaning they can be passed around and manipulated just like all other objects.

Models are classes -- you can tell from the fact that you create new models using class statements:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class AnthropomorphicBear(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Both the `Person` and `AnthropomorphicBear` identifiers are bound to Django classes, so you can pass them around. This can useful if you want to create helper functions that work at the model level (and share a common interface):

```
def print_obj_by_last_name(model, last_name):
    model_name = model.__name__
    matches = model.objects.filter(last_name=last_name).all()
    print('{0}: {1!r}'.format(model_name, matches))
```

So `print_obj_by_last_name` will work with either the `Person` or `AnthropomorphicBear` models. Just pass the model in like so:

```
print_obj_by_last_name(model=Person, last_name='Dole')
print_obj_by_last_name(model=AnthropomorphicBear, last_name='Fozzy')
```

Answer (score 0):

> model = django.authx.models.User
>
> ? Django returns an error, "global
>   name django is not defined."

Django does not return the error.  Python does.

First, you MUST import the model.  You must import it with

```
from django.authx.models import User
```

Second, if you get an error that `django` is not defined, then Django is not installed correctly.  You must have Django on your `PYTHONPATH` or installed in your Python lib/site-packages.

To install Django correctly, see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/install/#intro-install

Answer (score -3):

If you have the model name passed as a string I guess one way could be

```
modelname = "User"
model = globals()[modelname]
```

But mucking about with globals() might be a bit dangerous in some contexts. So handle with care :)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think most people are adverse to global variables - especially in a context like Django where the implication is that there might be something large and important behind it.