# How do I retrieve a Django form class dynamically?

Tags: django, forms

This question is inspired by another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411810/how-do-i-retrieve-a-django-model-class-dynamically). In the accepted answer the following method has been suggested to dynamically load any model:

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model
model = get_model('app_name', 'model_name')
```

Is there any equivalent for forms? I want to load a **specific form** from a **specific app** dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but figured I would add my answer since this was one of the questions I found while trying to make this work. I borrowed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016770/django-get-class-from-string) and was able to load a form dynamically using `getattr`:

```
from my_app import forms

custom_form = getattr(forms, 'CustomForm')()
```

This solution requires you to have the module already loaded.

I haven't tested it out, but you should be able to combine the above with dynamic module imports using the `import_module` function from `importlib` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module). The implementation would look something like:

```
from importlib import import_module

forms = import_module('my_app', 'forms')
custom_form = getattr(forms, 'CustomForm')()
```

This sort of dynamic class loading is used a lot by Django Oscar, so you could take a look at their code to see how they put this all together: https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/core/loading.py

Answer (score 0):

[Django applications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#module-django.apps) keep a list of available models. That makes it possible to have a [`get_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model) method.

The applications do not keep a list of available forms, so there is not an equivalent `get_forms` method.

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411810/how-do-i-retrieve-a-django-model-class-dynamically) you linked to and snippet you included was written in 2009. My links above are for Django 1.7, but the principle is the same for older and newer versions of Django.