# Django get class from string

Tags: generics, django-models, generic-programming, django-1.8, django-serializer

I'm looking for a generic way in Python to instantiate class by its name in similar way how it is done in Java without having to explicitly specify the class name in IF..ELIF condition.

This is because I have several different models and serializers and want to make them addressable by parameters in the HTTP request. It is to enhance loose coupling and modularity.

For example `https://www.domain.com/myapp/sampledata.json?model=<modelname>` should get the classes `<modelname>` and `<modelname>Serializer`.

There are some changes to this since Django 1.7 `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/`, before `get_model` was used for similar purpose.

> As of Django 1.7 the django.db.models.loading is deprecated (to be
>   removed in 1.9) in favor of the the new application loading system.

The warning:

> RemovedInDjango19Warning: The utilities in django.db.models.loading
>   are deprecated in favor of the new application loading system.
>   return f(*args, **kwds)

How should the following code be modified to get class from string?

views.py

```
from myapp.models import Samplemodel, Simplemodel1, Simplemodel2
from myapp.serializers import SamplemodelSerializer, Simplemodel1Serializer, Simplemodel2Serializer
from django.db.models.loading import get_model # deprecated
from myapp.jsonp_decorator import json_response

@json_response
def sampledata(request):

    model = request.GET.get('model','Samplemodel')

    if model=='Samplemodel':
        modelName = "Samplemodel"
        serializer = SamplemodelSerializer
    elif model=='Simplemodel1':
        modelName = "Simplemodel1"
        serializer = Simplemodel1Serializer
    elif model=='Simplemodel2':
        modelName = "Simplemodel2"
        serializer = Simplemodel2Serializer

    return serializer(get_model("myapp",modelName).objects.all(), many=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getattr`:

```
import my_serializers

serializer_class = getattr(my_serializers, 'SimpleSerializer')
serializer = serializer_class()
```

Comment: Seems to work with attributes, I need something similar with models and serializers

Comment: It will work for classes inside modules as well. They're attributes of the module.

Comment: You're right, it works well I'll post the updated code here.

Answer (score 1):

for Django 3+
the universal way to get the model instance:

```
def get_data_instance(model_name):
    """
    Try to find application with name "data" with specific "model_name"
    :param model_name: the name of the class
    :return: model instance or None
    """

    try:
        app_config = apps.get_app_config('data')
        return app_config.get_model(model_name)
    except LookupError:
        pass

    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to allow dynamic class loading in this case is:

```
from myapp import models
from myapp import serializers
from myapp.jsonp_decorator import json_response

@json_response
def sampledata(request):

    model = request.GET.get('model','Samplemodel')
    serializer_class = getattr(serializers, model+"Serializer")
    return serializer_class(getattr(models,modelName).objects.all(), many=True)
```